# Assign variations (simple) products to configurable. Magento 2 REST API

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I need to create configurable products with variations via REST API. I don't get how to do it. There is no reference in documentation.

What I have.

1. Created configurable type product
2. Created options to configurable
   product (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7355)

How to make `configurable_product_links` option ?

```
//example from admin configuration
"configurable_product_links":[
    107
]
```

Magento 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Only 5 years later... I needed to do this and couldn't find any documentation either, but I've managed to figure it out by matching the API response format from product data `GET` requests.

To add "Variation Products" which appear under the "Related Products, Up-Sells, and Cross-Sells, and Variations" tab in Magento admin, use a payload similar to the following:

Method: `PUT`

URL: `index.php/rest/all/V1/products/SKU1`

```json
{
    "product": {
        "product_links": [
            {
                "sku": "SKU1",
                "link_type": "variation",
                "linked_product_sku": "VARIANT1",
                "linked_product_type": "configurable",
                "position": 1
            },
            {
                "sku": "SKU1",
                "link_type": "variation",
                "linked_product_sku": "VARIANT2",
                "linked_product_type": "configurable",
                "position": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```